# Where is PLANT_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY set in sunflower app example?

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am using the sunflow app example (https://github.com/android/sunflower) as a basis to  learn Hilt, Room and many other nice concepts of android coding.

In the `PlantDetailViewModel` class there is this line:

`val plantId: String = savedStateHandle.get<String>(PLANT_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY)!!`.

But I cannot see nowhere in the entire project where `PLANT_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY` is set.
am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is set, to the string **plantId** in the `PlantDetailViewModel` class (at the bottom - line 55) using :-

```
companion object {
    private const val PLANT_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY = "plantId"
}
```

Comment: I have seen that, but that is just setting the value for the constant. What I mean is, something like `savedStateHandle.set(PLANT_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY, "theplant")` is missing in the entire project.